# How to answer phone calls in React Native?

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-native

So I'm trying to programmatically answer phone calls (on Android 10) in React Native. I tried using [react-native-callkeep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) but it seems that I can't figure out the documentation. Here's my code using the package:

```
// Listening on call state changes
    this.listener = EventRegister.addEventListener(
        CallManager.listenerName,
        type => {
            switch (type) {
                case CallManager.eventNames.Incoming:
                    self.setState({
                        isCurrentlyBeingCalled: true,
                    });
                    CallKeep.answerIncomingCall(); // This won't work

                    break;
            }
        },
    );
```

The documentation tells me to pass a `uuid` - but what uuid??? I tried using random uuids but that doesn't work either.

Does someone maybe know another better package to simply answer phone calls in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

If you look towards the lower end of the documentation, you will see the "Events" section. There you can register listeners which'll give you the callUUID so you can pass it into your method.

```
import RNCallKeep from 'react-native-callkeep';


RNCallKeep.addEventListener('didReceiveStartCallAction', ({ handle, callUUID, name }) => {
   console.log(`Received Start Call Event - Name: ${name}, Uuid: #{callUUID}`;
   RNCallKeep.answerIncomingCall(callUUID);
});
```

I haven't tested this, just what i compiled from the documentation, but try it out.